# URL Redirection in wordpress for search query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, plugins

I'm very new to Wordpress and using this plugin for redirection

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

I wanted to redirect a search query in the way that

> www.mywebsite.com/?s=abcd

gets redirected to

> www.mywebsite.com/?s=abcd&r_sortby=highest_rated

Could anyone help me on how can I achieve this using either the aforementioned plugin, or by using htaccess, or any other plugin?

I tried using Regular Expressions to but maybe I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is one thing you can do without using regular expressions, or plugins.

For the url you are posting seems that you are sorting your search results by highest rated, so the only thing you need to do is to add an input hidden with the name=r_sortby and value= highest_rated

Example:

```
<form name="searchform" role="search" method="GET" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" name="r_sortby" value="highest_rated" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This is just a generic form but it can be used with wordpress for what you are trying to do, without any plugins or .htaccess